# Select with NVL2 Not working Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am selecting values from the database using Functions. I have three different functions in which if the first does not return anything I check for the second and third functions for values using NVL2. The problem is when I execute independent functions they return values but not in the NVL2 function My query is:

```
select  NVL2(CRBP.FPDATE(LAM.ACID), 
             CRBP.FPDATE1(LAM.ACID),
             CRBP.ODSANCDATE(GAM.ACID)) from 
 tbaadm.lam, TBAADM.GAM
where gam.acid = lam.acid
  and gam.acid = 'VM12990'
```

This does not return any value.

But when I execute :

```
select CRBP.FPDATE (LAM.ACID) from tbaadm.lam where lam.acid = 'VM12990';
```

This Already returns a value. Shouldn't this be the value returned by my first query considering that it is the first in the check. What is the Problem with My first Query??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If CRBP.FPDATE returns a value the query should return the value returned by the function CRBP.FPDATE1 and if CRBP.FPDATE returns NULL then the query should return CRBP.ODSANCDATE's vlaue.

Does CRBP.FPDATE1 return anything?

Comment: On this Particular acid = 'VM12990', the other two returns null, so I expect that the value returned is whichever which is not null

Comment: @Stanley Then you need to replace `NVL2` with `coalesce` function. `NVL2` works as suggested by pablomatico but `coalesce` returns the first not null from the list.

Comment: @San You are right. I Replaced NVL2 with Coalesce and it works. Thanks.. Accepting this Answer. +1 for That suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`NVL2(a,b,c)` is a "if a is null then a else b" type function.  so the value of a is never returned.

it sounds like you want `COALESCE` which will return the first not null value from the set of parameters